# Converting output from subprocess to csv.reader object

Tags: csv, python-3.x, subprocess

Is there a way to take the output from subprocess and turn it into an iterable csv.reader or csv.DictReader object? Here's the code I've been trying:

```
p2 = subprocess.Popen("sort command...", stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output = p2.communicate()[0]
edits = csv.reader(output, delimiter="\t")
```

Basically, I'm sorting a large CSV file, and then I'd like to get it into Python as a csv.reader object.

The error I'm getting is

> Error: iterator should return strings, not int (did you open the file in text mode?)

Is there a way to treat this bytestream as a csv.reader object, or am I thinking about things the wrong way?

Comment: ...to be honest, I'd be very tempted to do something like `'sort command' | python pythonscript.py` and just have the python script read from sys.stdin.

Comment: That's my plan for now, if I can't figure this out. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a problem in Python 3. The CSV module needs unicode input, not byte strings. In addition to this, `csv.reader()` needs an iterable such as an open file or a list of strings. Try this:

```
encoding = 'ascii'    # specify the encoding of the CSV data
p2 = subprocess.Popen(['sort', '/tmp/data.csv'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output = p2.communicate()[0].decode(encoding)
edits = csv.reader(output.splitlines(), delimiter=",")
for row in edits:
    print(row)
```

If `/tmp/data.csv` contains (I've used commas as the separator):

```
1,2,3,4
9,10,11,12
a,b,c,d
5,6,7,8
```

then the output would be:

```
['1', '2', '3', '4']
['5', '6', '7', '8']
['9', '10', '11', '12']
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

Comment: you could [use `universal_newlines=True` to enable text mode](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31459332/4279) (to use the preferred locale encoding). Note: [`str.splitlines` may split on non-'\r\n' characters](http://bugs.python.org/issue22232)

Answer (score 3):

The following works for me (even though the docs warn about reading from `stdout`). Wrapping `stdout` with an `io.TextIOWrapper()` supports newlines embedded in the data for fields.

Doing this allows a generator to be used which has the advantage of allowing `stdout` to be read incrementally, one line at at time.

```
p2 = subprocess.Popen(["sort", "tabbed.csv"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output = io.TextIOWrapper(p2.stdout, newline=os.linesep)
edits = csv.reader((line for line in output), delimiter="\t")
for row in edits:
    print(row)
```

Output:

```
['1', '2', '3', '4']
['5', '6', '7', '8']
['9', '10', '11', '12']
['a', 'b\r\nx', 'c', 'd']
```

The `tabbed.csv` input test file contained this (where `»` represents tab characters and the `≡` a newline character):

```
1»2»3»4
9»10»11»12
a»"b≡x"»c»d
5»6»7»8
```

Comment: You should pass a list instead of the string as a command on POSIX systems (`"sort tabbed.csv"` will fail). Also, [to enable embedded newlines, you could use `io.TextIOWrapper()`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31459332/4279).

Comment: use `newline=""` to support files created on other systems (as `csv` docs recommend)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: I didn't because this isn't a file created on another system and doing so would not support embedded newlines.

Comment: `newline=os.linesep` does not make any sense compared to `newline=""`. 1. `csv` creates files with `\r\n` regardless of the system: why would you use  `os.linesep`? Anyway why would you actively reject files from other systems? 2. `csv`  *"reader is hard-coded to recognize either '\r' or '\n' as end-of-line"* -- it is misleading to provide `newline=os.linesep` (universal newlines mode is off) here. 3. You should pass `newline` parameter to `TextIOWrapper` (to avoid corrupting embedded newlines). Note: `newline=''` means that universal newlines is on but newlines are passed untranslated.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: How `csv` creates files isn't relevant here, where a `csv.reader` is being used to read output being piped in from the `stdout` of another program running locally. I _am_ passing a `newline` keyword argument to `TextIOWrapper`.  Perhaps you're confusing its `newline` parameter with the `csv` module's `Dialect.lineterminator` which is only used by `csv.writers`. FWIW, all versions of my answer were actually run with the input described and produced the output shown before being posted.

Answer (score 1):

To enable text mode, pass `universal_newlines=True` parameter:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import csv
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

with Popen(["sort", "a.csv"], stdout=PIPE, universal_newlines=True) as p:
    print(list(csv.reader(p.stdout, delimiter="\t")))
```

If you need to interpret newlines embedded inside quoted fields then create `io.TextIOWrapper`, to pass `newline=''` parameter:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import csv
import io
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

with Popen(["sort", "a.csv"], stdout=PIPE) as p, \
     io.TextIOWrapper(p.stdout, newline='') as text_file:
    print(list(csv.reader(text_file, delimiter="\t")))
```

Also, `TextIOWrapper` allows to specify the character encoding explicitly (otherwise the default `locale.getpreferredencoding(False)` is used).

Note: you don't need the external `sort` command. You could sort the lines in pure Python:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import csv

with open('a.csv', newline='') as text_file:
    rows = list(csv.reader(text_file, delimiter="\t"))
    rows.sort()
    print(rows)
```

Note: the later version sorts csv rows instead of physical lines (you could sort the lines if you want).

Answer (score 0):

This works if your CSV file has column headings.

```
[ user@system currentDir ]$ ./ProgramThatCreatesCSVData
first,second,third,fourth
1,2,3,4
9,10,11,12
a,b,c,d
5,6,7,8
[ user@system currentDir ]$
[ user@system currentDir ]$
[ user@system currentDir ]$
[ user@system currentDir ]$ cat CSVtoDict.py
#!/usr/bin/python3
"""Sample program to open a pipe to run a command.
That command generates a CSV with heading names in the first row.
Output of this program is a conversion of that CSV to a list of dictionaries,
in pprint format."""

import csv, pprint, subprocess, io

pipe = subprocess.Popen(["./ProgramThatCreatesCSVData"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
pipeWrapper = io.TextIOWrapper(pipe.stdout)
pipeReader = csv.DictReader(pipeWrapper)
listOfDicts = [ dict(row) for row in pipeReader ]

pprint.pprint(listOfDicts)

[ user@system currentDir ]$
[ user@system currentDir ]$
[ user@system currentDir ]$
[ user@system currentDir ]$ python3 CSVtoDict.py
[{'first': '1', 'fourth': '4', 'second': '2', 'third': '3'},
 {'first': '9', 'fourth': '12', 'second': '10', 'third': '11'},
 {'first': 'a', 'fourth': 'd', 'second': 'b', 'third': 'c'},
 {'first': '5', 'fourth': '8', 'second': '6', 'third': '7'}]
[ user@system currentDir ]$
```